# How can I run a soundcloud file on the onload procedure in a html file

Tags: html, soundcloud

I want to replace an existing miniplayer on a website which starts playing after opening the page though an onload JavaScript.

Comment: What is the part you are having trouble with? Run JavaScript on page load or loading the Soundcloud track?

Answer (score 0):

The soundcloud custom player widget has an autoplay option which looks like it would suit your needs.

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player